# how to create new dataframe by extract row corresponding to ID values from old dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am using the Wisconsin Breast Cancer dataset from [UCI Machine Learning repository](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/breast+cancer+wisconsin+(diagnostic)) in r. There are total of 569 observations.

Read the Data.

```r
df <- readxl::read_excel("./wdbc.xlsx")
```

create bootstrap samples.

```r
k = 20
n = nrow(df)

bootSamples = as.data.frame(matrix(sample(df$ID, size = k*n, replace = TRUE), k, n))
colnames(bootSamples) <- paste0("Column", seq(ncol(bootSamples)))
```

My doubt is how to create a new data frame in r by using ID value from 1st bootstrap column and extract row corresponding to ID value from original dataframe (1st photo) to new dataframe ?

Comment: Please add a reproducible example and code snippets instead of pictures to allow for better answers, for you and future readers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: I think you don't need to use the IDs at all, just sample the row numbers, i.e. `sample(nrow(df), ...)`. And you probably don't want to use the columns of `bootSamples` but rather its rows. So in the end you would use something like `df[bootSamples[1, ], ]`.